# Notation: What does it mean to say $G(x) = F(x+)$ in Folland's Real Analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

I Folland's *Real Analysis*, I came across to the following theorem,

> **3.23 Theorem.** Let $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be increasing, and let $G(x) = F(x+)$.
>
> 1. The set of points at which $F$ is discontinuous is countable.
> 2. $F$ and $G$ are differentiable a.e., and $F'=G'$ a.e.

What does $G(x) = F(x+)$ mean?

Comment: It could mean the one-sided limit (approaching $x$ from the right, as in $f(x+0)$). But I'm not sure.

Comment: You should provide much more context. Which book is this? What was being discussed at this point in the book? What were the preceding and following sentences?

Comment: This could mean the positive part of $x$, as in $x$ if $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise.  Or it could be a typo.  Give more context and maybe somebody will have a better idea for you.

Comment: I added context. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can mean a variety of things:

I am 99% percent sure it is used for:
$$f(x+)=\lim_{y\to x^+}f(y)$$
I have seen it used however as:
$$f(x+)=\begin{cases} f(x), \ x\in D_f:f(x)>0\\
0, \ x\in D_f:f(x)<0\end{cases}$$
(we usually use $f_+$ for that)
or even in an old extreme book:
$$f(x+)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$
(we usually use $f^{\prime}_+$ or $f^{\prime}(x+)$ for that). It could of course
denote something else like the principle part of $f$ but I doubt it