# Folland's real analysis, what does notation $x+$ mean

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Folland's *Real Analysis*, theorem 3.23, the notation $F(x+)$ comes without definition as follows:

> **3.23 Theorem.** Let $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be increasing, and let $G(x) = F(x+)$.
>
> 1. The set of points at which $F$ is discontinuous is countable.
> 2. $F$ and $G$ are differentiable a.e., and $F'=G'$ a.e.
>
> *Proof*. Since $F$ is increasing, the intervals $(F(x-), F(x+)) (x\in\mathbb{R})$ are disjoint, ...

So I hope to ask:

1. What does $G(x) = F(x+)$ mean?
2. One previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265552/notation-what-does-it-mean-to-say-gx-fx-in-follands-real-analysis) says it means one-sided limit. If so, then why are intervals $(F(x-), F(x+)) (x\in\mathbb{R})$ disjoint?

> **My attempt 1**:
> Assume $x_1<x_2$, i.e., $x_2 = x_1 + \delta$ for some $\delta> 0$. Since $F$ is increasing, $F(x_2) = F(x_1) + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.
>
> $$F(x_1+) = \lim_{y\to x_1+}F(y) = \lim_{h>0, h\to 0}F(x_1+h) = F(x_1)+\varepsilon_1$$
> $$F(x_2-) = \lim_{y\to x_2-}F(y) = \lim_{h>0, h\to 0}F(x_2-h) = F(x_2)-\varepsilon_2$$
> where $\varepsilon_1>0, \varepsilon_2>0$.

Question: I think $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ should be $0$, but that seems to require the continuity of $F$, which is not assumed. Am I going in the right direction?

> **My attempt 2**:
> Assume $x_1<x_2$, and there exists $y\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $x_1<y<x_2$ since $\mathbb{R}$ is dense. We have
> $$F(x+) = \lim_{z\searrow x}F(z) = \inf_{z>x}F(z)$$
> $$F(x-) = \lim_{z\nearrow x}F(z) = \sup_{z<x}F(z)$$
> Thus for any $x_1<y<x_2$:
> $$F(x_2-) = \sup_{z<x_2}F(z) \geq F(y)$$
> $$F(x_1+) = \inf_{z>x_1}F(z) \leq F(y)$$
> $$F(x_2-) - F(x_1+) \geq F(y) - F(y) = 0$$
> So we are done.

Question: Is this attempt correct?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You already know the answer of your first question. For the second you may begin by showing that if $x \leq y$ then $F(x^+) \leq F(y^-)$.

Comment: @blamethelag Thanks a lot! I tried your approach and updated the question with my attempt, which seems to require assuming continuity. Could you kindly check it?

Comment: I disagree with the last equalities of your computations, you don't know if $F$ is right/left continuous. You should replace them with inequalities.

Comment: $F(x+)=\lim_{z\searrow x} F(z)$, $F(x-)=\lim_{z\nearrow x}F(z)$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3763555/121671)

Comment: @Mittens Thank you! I updated my second attempt in the question. Could you kindly check whether it's correct?

Comment: @sam2018: the argument in your attempt seems fine.

Comment: @blamethelag It's not true that if $x\le y$, $F(x^+)\le F(y^-)$. Consider $x=y$.